# Catch Java generated JFrame pop-up

Tags: java, testing, junit, listener, jframe

I'll make it short and specific. I am blackbox testing a commandline utility in Java (IDE: Eclipse) and at some point it generates a JFrame pop-up, which asks for password. Since I'm making series of automated tests, the password has to be entered automatically. There is no button on the popup so password + enter key is enough.

Should I make somekind of listener or eventhandler, which is waiting for the pop-up, catch it and enter the password? Maybe somekind of process listener?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Give your input field and your button a name (Component.setName()) and use the FEST framework to robot control your UI: http://fest.easytesting.org/

But: for cases like this it might be more interesting to be able to give the passwd and username either via the commandline (bypassing the gui) or read it from a config file. (Both will later likely be added to the utillity anyway)

Comment: Since I am not generating the input field, I cannot set anything (I'm writing JUnit tests).

There is a possibility to enter password via command line actually, but when I then try to run the utility via Eclipse, I'll get a "no console" error. It occurs because it's a long time problem of console class and IDE integration, as far as I know.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the developers to give the input field a name with "setName"? You can use the framework I have linked above also if the name of the input field is not set. It is basically an extension to java.awt.Robot that allows you to wait for a Frame to oen and then you can inspect the tree of UI elements and manipulate them (like entering text or clicking a button)